# javascript regex to replace all img src with data-src

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to replace all img src with data-src and this is my pattern :

```
(<img.*?)src
```

but this one is also matching data-src so when i use in on a loop it ouput something like that

```
<img data-data-data-data-data-data-data-data-data-data-data-data-data-data-src="..">
```

any help ?

Comment: Why would you be running this over and over in a loop?

Comment: Use the `/g` flag, don't run the same pattern in a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regexp for this. Just

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var img = images[i];
  img.dataset.src = img.src;
  img.src = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Positive look aheads would be helpfull

```
<img(?![^>\n]*data-src)[^>\n]*src
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/oF5qB8/2)

Answer (score 0):

`(<img.*?)[^-]src` will work, but regexes try to get the longest match, so

```
(<img[^>])[^->]src
```

would ne more correct.